# Python os.getcwd paths

Tags: python

I'm using os.listdir() to get all the files from a directory and dump them out to a txt file. I'm going to use the txt file to import into access to generate hyperlinks. The problem I'm having is getting the correct path. So when the script is ran it uses whatever directory you are in. Here is an example. Right now it half works, it create links.txt, but there is nothing in the text file.

```
myDirectory = os.listdir("links")
f.open("links.txt", "w")
f.writelines([os.getcwd %s % (f) for f in myDirectory])
```

Comment: Here is the way I was doing it before but it's a hardlink, it needed it more dynamic depending on where the script is run. 

f.writelines(['file:////links/%s\n' % (f) for f in myDirectory])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of yours:

```
f.writelines([os.getcwd %s % (f) for f in myDirectory])
```

is invalid Python syntax and it's very hard to guess what you had in mind for it -- for example, why would you care about the current directory when `myDirectory` lists, not files in the current directory, but rather files in subdirectory "links"?

Trying to read your mind is always a difficult and generally unrewarding exercise, but assuming you do mean to use the current directory, you might want

```
 f.writelines(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f) for f in myDirectory)
```

Comment: That did it. Sorry for making you a jedi on that one. I'm still learning programing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `os.getcwd()` with the trailing parens.

What you probably actually want here though is `os.path.join()`

Answer (score 0):

os.getcwd is a function you need to call... also I'm not sure what you're doing with the string escape % - but they only work inside strings... I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
f.writelines([os.path.join(os.getcwd(),f) for f in myDirectory])
```

[Edit: os.path.join from Alex Martelli's better answer]